# Debian Wheezy: unmet dependencies when starting program

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to run a program and it tells me it needs the packages:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

After that, i get this error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.27) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 (>= 2.4.23) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.17) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libffi5:i386 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 8.0.5-4+deb7u2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-xcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What i already tried as commands:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: The clue is in the last line; you have held broken packages. "Held" packages are held in a fixed state and cannot be upgraded / removed. If you have `aptitude` installed, you can use `aptitude search ~i | grep ^ih` to find which packages those are; with `aptitude unhold packagename` you can undo the hold.

Comment: Your command just returned nothing. It just goes back to the command prompt.

Comment: Strange... you can run `aptitude` without options which gives you an interactive screen. See if it shows that there are broken packages. You can hit `b` to jump to the next broken package. See the help (`?`) for other keys; basically `+` to select the highlighted package for installation, `-` to mark it to be removed, `g` to go and perform the changes (you get a preview first).

Comment: It shows me some conflicts, but it does not show me libc6